# Не срабатывает условие в node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Пишу игру игру для тестового задания.

Как должно быть:
Два пользователя заходят на сервер, выбирают один из предложенных вариантов, кликают по "Жми, если выбор сделан!" и им приходит ответ: если результат совпадает, то появляется alert "Ты выиграл!" у обоих игроков.

Как есть на самом деле: игроки кликают одинаковый результат и ничего не происходит.

Почему так?

Сам код здесь:
https://repl.it/repls/PapayawhipRundownShell

```js
// подключение express и socket.io 
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var path = require('path'); 

var port = 8080;

var connections = [];

var playerOne;
var playerTwo;
// массив для хранения текущих подключений 
var connections = [];

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

// установка соединения
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
 connections.push(socket.id);
 if (connections.length > 0) {
  console.log('Connected: %s sockets connected', connections.length);
  console.log(connections);
 }
 if (connections.length != 2) {
  socket.emit('wait', 'Вас должно быть двое. Ни больше - ни меньше.' ); 
 } 
 else {
   socket.on('send message', function (data) {
    if (socket.id = connections[0]) {
     playerOne = data;
     console.log(playerOne); 
    } else if  (socket.id = connections[1]) {
     playerTwo = data;
     console.log(playerTwo);
    }
    
   })
   if ((playerOne) && (playerTwo)){
     socket.emit('answer', 'Ты выиграл!' ); 
   }
 }
 
})

server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('app running on port ' + port); 
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Камень, ножницы, бумага, ящерица, спок.</title>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div>
  <fieldset class="ad-form__element">
          <label class="ad-form__label" for="type">Выбирай жест!</label>
          <select id="type" name="type">
            <option value="Спок">Спок</option>
            <option value="Камень">Камень</option>
            <option value="Ножницы">Ножницы</option>
            <option value="Ящерица">Ящерица</option>
   <option value="Бумага">Бумага</option>
          </select>
        </fieldset>
  <button class="ad-form__submit" type="submit">Жми, если выбор сделан!</button>
  <div id="output"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js"></script>
 <script>

   var socket = io();
   var usersChoise = document.querySelector('#type').value;
   var btn = document.querySelector('.ad-form__submit'); 
   btn.onclick = function () {
  console.log(document.querySelector('#type').value);
        // сгенерировать событие отправки сообщения 
        socket.emit('send message', document.querySelector('#type').value); 
   }
   socket.on('answer', function (data) {
  alert(data);
    })
    </script>
</html>
```

UPD: я узнал, что из-за срабатывающего выше события 'wait', не приходит ответ с того клиента, у которого он появился.
Если его закомментировать, то к серверу приходит оба сообщения, но даже если закомментировать его, то не срабатывает условие для победы.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: А как мне выложить код от node.js, если не ссылкой?

Comment: Когда вы создаёте/правите вопрос - на панели есть кнопка "фрагмент кода" и чуть дальше "фрагмент кода на html+css+js". Сделал вам для образца. Такие фрагменты можно даже запускать - прямо с сайта stackoverflow.